# maclaurin series in J

Tags: math, j, taylor-series

I'm trying to implement the series expansion for sine(x) in J (I'm not worried about accuracy, but more the problem of expressing the series nicely).

So far I have the following explicit version which computes sine(pi) using 50 terms:

3.14 (4 :'+/((_1^y) * (x^(1+2*y)) % !1+2*y)')  i.50

But it seems somewhat clunky, is there a "better" version (maybe tacit?) ?

Comment: The quotient between two terms of the series is `(-x*x)/((2*k)*(2*k+1))`. Can you implement this as a one-liner, i.e., start with `term=1`, `k=1`, `sum=0`, loop: add `term` to `sum`, multiply `term` with the next quotient, increase `k` by 1, end loop (with `k=50`), return `x*sum`.

Comment: yes, but then you have an explicit do-loop it seems which is not array processing...

Answer (score 3):

You want a list of odd numbers for powers and factorials: `l =: >:+:i. y` (`>:@+:@i.`) or `>:@+:` if your y is `i.`.

Then, you want the powers (x^l) divided by the factorials (!l). One way is to see this as a fork `(x f y) h (x g y)` -> `(x ^ l) % (x (]!) l)` → `(^ % (]!))`.

The last step is to multiply this series by the series `1, _1, 1, ...`: `_1 ^ y` → `_1&^`

So, the final form is `(_1 ^ y) * (x (^ * (]!)) (>:@+:@i.) y)` which is the **train** `(h y) j (x f (g y))` → `(h y) j (x (f g) y)` → `(x (]h) y) j (x (f g) y)` → `(]h) j (f g)`:

```
ms =: (] _1&^)  *   ((^ % (]!)) (>:@+:))
+/ 3.14 ms i.50 
0.00159265
```

or

```
f =: +/@(ms i.)
3.14 f 50
0.00159265
```

On the other hand, you can use `T.` for [the taylor approximation](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dtcapdot.htm).

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for.  A tacit version, with a step-by-step derivation.  As a beginner, simply being presented with a solution is often not very rewarding.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

```
   3.14 (4 :'+/((_1^y) * (x^(1+2*y)) % !1+2*y)') i.50
0.00159265
```

Tacit version could look like this:

```
   3.14 +/@:((_1 ^ ]) * ([ ^ 1 + +:@]) % !@(1 + +:@])) i.50
0.00159265
```

or this:

```
   3.14 +/@:((_1 ^ ]) * ([ ^ >:@+:@]) % !@>:@+:@]) i.50
0.00159265
```

or even this:

```
   3.14 +/@:((_1 ^ ]) * (( ^  % !@])(>:@+:@]))) i.50
0.00159265
```

The first and second are pretty much tacit translations, the last uses hooks and forks, which can be a bit much unless you are used to them.